# How to create @Transient properties in JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

I was thinking about how to create a Proposal object like this in JHipster: so a User can create a Proposal and other users can vote for it.

```
entity Proposal {
    proposalText String  minlength(2) maxlength(100) required
    proposalVotes Integer
}
entity Vote {
    numberOfPoints Integer
}
relationship ManyToOne {
    Vote{proposal(id) required} to Proposal{vote}
    Proposal{user(id) required} to User{proposal}
    Vote{user(id) required} to User{vote}
}
```

In Spring I would create that @Transient proposalVotes Integer and the Controller would go and find all the Votes that a Proposal has and add them together to get to the result to be sent to the frontend. That property would not be stored in the database.

If I use JHipster and I add a proposalVotes property, the result would be saved in the database and could be changed in the dialogs(... and I do not like the result), so my question is:
What is the best practice in JHipster when you need a property that is calculated everytime his object is called?

Think of the number of comments in a Blog with Posts, if it is more familiar.

Where do you calculate the result: I would do it in the ProposalResource, but I’m not sure and I haven’t seen any use case like this in the examples, but it looks like a common case.

Thanks a lot

PD: If there is any example in Github, that could be great!

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from adding this annotation to generated code? Alternatively you can use DTOs and service layer.

Comment: Thanks once more, Gaël. Yes, being new to programming! ;-) that is why I ask you, as an expert, how would you do it? Is that the best practice? I think I will have to modified a whole bunch of things. Do you know of any similar example that I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you are generating entities using JDL(Jhipster domain language) then you wont get any option to make field `Transient` as JDL is database design mechanism and `Transient` fields are not going to be placed in DB.

Solution is that **after importing JDL to our app** you can add `Transient` fields in your entity class.

Comment: How would you do it? Do you know of any similar example that I can look at?

Comment: Follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fbEnchNPHSc tutorial in which 12:15 time he is creating an new entity using command line and then in your source code that Entity class is getting generated so in that class you can create Transient fields (14:20 time).

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. However, the video does not explain how to add Transient fields.

Comment: yes but i just wanted to show you by that video.. where and which stage exactly you can create transient fields...thanks

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, but you can not do it there. You have to create everything and then change things from de IDE (domain, Resource, etc) and I really can not figure out, how exactly. Do you know what, where and how? Do you have any code to see? Thanks again.

Comment: @Alien all this kind of solutions have a drawback: during the workflow I call for the entity generation several times. Each time I call it I add this manually again.

Comment: and also, jHipster creates liquobase and db schema genration. So it turns that you are creating a column for this field, but then just making JPA to ignore if with adding the Transiend after the generation.